# Make.git open in ssh

Tags: ssh, putty, .git-folder

I have download a git with a wget on a vps through putty.

I see the file is listed on the vps like so:

```
bitcoin-sniffer.git  .lastlogin     .python_history
```

Now how can I execute the .git, or actually use the files that are within it? I have tried

```
 git clone bitcoin-sniffer.git
```

The error:

```
fatal: destination path 'bitcoin-sniffer.git' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Comment: How did you get that `bitcoin-sniffer.git` directory?  Did you download it using `git clone`, or some other way?  Is it a bare repository, or does it have a working copy?

Comment: wget was the method

Comment: It sounds like you downloaded a bare repository from somewhere, which is generally not what you want.  Typically you want to `git clone` from the remote repository to get a local copy that you can work with.  (It sounds like you're not very familiar with Git or what it's meant for — I'd recommend reading some introductory documentation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the `git clone` command is followed by an address with **ssh** or **HTTPS** path to download a repo. The git command is not run against a *.git "package".

An example would be:
`bash
git clone https://github.com/sebicas/bitcoin-sniffer.git`

This would download and create a folder by the name `bitcoin-sniffer`. Within this folder, git commands can be run, like `git status`.

Answer (score 1):

The "git" you acquired is a full git repository, with the entire history of the protect and all the information you need to get the current state of the files. Judging by the `.git` extension, I would assume that the repository is "bare", meaning that it only contains the compressed history but not a working copy of the current state of the project. Conventionally, bare repos have a `.git` extension, while a full working copy would have a `.git` folder in the project root.

Your intuition to clone the repository to get a working copy is correct. It's not working because by default, `git clone` running locally will try to make a folder with the same name as the repo. Give it a different folder name as an additional parameter instead:

```
git clone bitcoin-sniffer.git bitcoin-sniffer
```

This is actually doing an extra step in all probability. You can clone directly from a remote location using either SSH or HTTPS. If your project comes from GitHub, for example, you can get a read-only copy (that you can modify locally but not push back) anonymously over HTTPS:

```
git clone https://github.com/sebicas/bitcoin-sniffer.git
```

You really shouldn't be getting "gits" using WGET under normal circumstances.

Comment: there we go thanks. now if only you could help me with this sudo issue lol